# nginx running as root and user (cant kill user)

Tags: nginx, ubuntu-14.04

```
ubuntu@Nginx:~$ ps -ef |grep nginx
root      1854     1  0 07:46 ?        00:00:00 nginx: master process /usr/sbin/nginx
www-data  1855  1854  0 07:46 ?        00:00:00 nginx: worker process
www-data  1856  1854  0 07:46 ?        00:00:00 nginx: worker process
www-data  1857  1854  0 07:46 ?        00:00:00 nginx: worker process
www-data  1858  1854  0 07:46 ?        00:00:00 nginx: worker process
ubuntu    1880  1772  0 07:47 pts/4    00:00:00 grep --color=auto nginx
ubuntu@Nginx:~$ sudo service nginx stop
ubuntu@Nginx:~$ ps -ef |grep nginx
ubuntu    1895  1772  0 07:47 pts/4    00:00:00 grep --color=auto nginx
ubuntu@Nginx:~$ ps -ef |grep nginx
ubuntu    1897  1772  0 07:47 pts/4    00:00:00 grep --color=auto nginx
ubuntu@Nginx:~$ ps -ef |grep nginx
ubuntu    1899  1772  0 07:47 pts/4    00:00:00 grep --color=auto nginx
```

This happened last time to me when I installed from scratch but I don't remember how I fixed it. When I boot I get nginx running as my user? I'm not sure how or why and it's constantly chaning its PID. I can't see to be able to kill it and it seems to be interfering with the nginx (its not running correctly any more).

Edit I ran Kill -9 on my own self and when I logged back in I the process was running again. What locations could be starting this thing as me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mis-reading the output of `ps | grep` after you have (successfully) stopped the nginx process:

```
ubuntu    1895  1772  0 07:47 pts/4    00:00:00 grep --color=auto nginx
```

This isn't the nginx server, it's `grep` matching *itself* because it also contains the word *"nginx"* on its command line, and you're searching for that word. That's also why the PID changes: you are starting a new `grep` each time.

If you want to leave out `grep` from the result, try this:

```
$ ps -ef | grep nginx | grep -v grep
```

(`-v grep` means *"don't match any lines that contain the word 'grep"*)